# viewMode bootstrap datetimepicker desabilitar meses e anos

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div class="input-group date dtPicker @Html.GeneratePermssionID(item.IntegrationId)" style="width: 200px;" id="dateFrom" data-pl="5">                                                                                                                   
<span class="input-group-addon">De:</span>
@if (item.IntegrationExecutionStats == IntegrationExecutionStats.Running)
{
<input type="text" class="form-control dateFrom @Html.GeneratePermssionID(item.IntegrationId)" data-pl="5" placeholder="___/___/___" disabled>
}
else
{
<input type="text" class="form-control dateFrom @Html.GeneratePermssionID(item.IntegrationId)" data-pl="5" placeholder="___/___/___">
}
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
```

quero estabelecer que o calendario mostre apenas os dias (nao permitindo acessar mes ou ano). coloquei o seguinte script logo abaixo
da div mas nao funciona. o que está errado?

```
$("#dateFrom").datepicker( {
viewMode: "days", 
maxViewMode: "days"
});
```

Comment: Tentou usar o datepicker de jquery ui? https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/